# Eval of form runs entire file unless I switch to namespace in repl

Tags: vim, clojure, nrepl

I am using this, and I think I have some odd behavior.  I open a repl at the project root (`foons`), open a file (`ex.clj`) file with vim in the project, and then eval the following (both with `<,>Eval` and `cpp` inside the form) :

`(clojure.core/in-ns 'foons.ex)`

When I do this, it seems that the whole file gets evaluated, not just the form I select, which I think is incorrect.

However, if I change to `foons.ex` namespace in the repl I launched, and do the same `in-ns` command inside of Vim, I get the expected behavior, and just the form evaluates, not the whole file.

Is this a bug, or do I possibly have something configured wrong?

Specs:

> Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 13.0.1 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>
> Clojure: 1.10.0
>
> nrepl: 0.6.0

I also opened bug here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/issues/373

Comment: Just as a side-note: wasn't `Eval` dropped in fireplace in favour of `Clj(s)Eval`? I am not saying, that this is realted, but it could indicate, that you are using an old fireplace version?

Comment: The latests build seems to be Dec. 15, 2019, and there is no mention there of deprecation.  I would think Clj(s)Eval is for Clojurescript, not main Clojure... but thanks.

Comment: `CljEval` is not for cljs, `CljsEval` is - but that release seems recent anyway.  just wanted to check

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the github issue I filed here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/issues/373

To summarize the answer, it is behaving as designed.  From the issue:

> If I understand correctly it is working as intended. Fireplace's :Eval always happens inside the current file's namespace, which means we need to require it beforehand if it isn't already defined.